# Jasper plugin not appear in Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaspersoft-studio

I installed the eclipse new version & also I need `JasperSoft Studio` for it as I am already working on a project which had some old `Jasper Reports`. I tried to install the JasperSoft Studio through marketplace which I did last time it was there but now & I did not found it.
Anyone had this experience? did they change something? I can see the latest rlease of Jasper Studio is 25-01-2024.

My eclipse details are: -

- `version:` 2023-12 (4.30.0)
- `Build id:` 20231201-2043
- `Java version:` 17.0.10

[image]

How can I install jasper studio?

Comment: Have you checked with them for possible updated installation instructions?

Comment: Well, I tried to find out the option, but not successded yet.